# How to do better text search in neo4j

Tags: solr, neo4j, lucene, cypher

I have two types of nodes Article and TAG where  TAG have two properties id and name. Now I want to search all the articles according to tags.

```
(a : Article)-[:TAGGED]->(t : TAG)
```

e.g If I  have tags like "i love my country" and my query string is "country" then search is successfully using the following query.

```
Match (a : Article)-[:TAGGED]->(t : TAG) 
where t.name =~ '*.country.*' 
return a;
```

But its vice-versa is not possible like if my tag is "country" and I search for "i love my country" then it should also display the articles related to country. It should also handle the case when user have entered more than one space between the two words. On searching I came accross lucene and solr but I don't know how to use them. And I am using PHP as my coding language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDITED]

### Original Answer

This should work for you:

```
MATCH (a: Article)-[:TAGGED]->(t:TAG)
WHERE ANY(word IN FILTER(x IN SPLIT({searchString}, " ") WHERE x <> '') 
  WHERE t.name CONTAINS word)
RETURN a;
```

`{searchString}` is your search string, with one or spaces separating words; e.g.:

```
"i  love my    country"
```

This snippet generates a collection of the non-empty words in `{searchString}`:

```
FILTER(x IN SPLIT({searchString}, " ") WHERE x <> '')
```

### Improved Answer

This query matches on words (e.g., if the query string is "i love you", the "i" will only match "i" or "I" as a word in the tag, not just any letter "i"). It is also case insensitive.

```
WITH REDUCE(res = [], w IN SPLIT({searchString}, " ") |
  CASE WHEN w <> '' THEN res + ("(?i).*\\b" + w + "\\b.*") ELSE res END) AS res
MATCH (a: Article)-[:TAGGED]->(t:TAG)
WHERE ANY (regexp IN res WHERE t.name =~ regexp)
RETURN a;
```

The `REDUCE` clause generates a collection of words from `{searchString}`, each surrounded by `"(?i).*\b"` and `"\b.*"` to become a regular expression for doing a case insensitive search with word boundaries.

NOTE: the backslashes (`"\"`) in the regular expression actually have to be doubled-up because the backslash is an escape charater.

Comment: How to make this query case insensitive ?

Comment: I have done it in some other way, I have covert both the words searchString and tagged keyword in lower case and do the matching.

MATCH (a: Article)-[:TAGGED]->(t:TAG)
WHERE ANY(word IN FILTER(x IN SPLIT({searchString}, " ") WHERE x <> '')  WHERE lower(t.name) CONTAINS lower(word)) RETURN a;

Is it also a correct method or it may fail in some conditions ?

Comment: Your approach (based on my original answer) will not find just words -- but I don't know if that is important to you. Your approach will work as a case insensitive search, but it *may* be more inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the changes made my me to support case insensitivity will make the query more inefficient. I will follow your updated answer, but when I execute your query it is not returning any node/row. e.g. My tagged word is "India" and my searchString is "India is my country".

Comment: Fixed my answer to use `\b` insead of `\W`. It should now work properly.

Comment: +1 for a working solution, but a word of caution:   This is the graph-db equivalent of a table-scan with heavy string operations on each row.  As long as the number of Tags stays small, you should be okay.  If you start getting a big influx of Tags, this will slow you down and consume unnecessary computing resources.  Whereas, within neo4j, if you can get Lucene to do what it's designed for, the matching part of this operation will execute in milliseconds (even with hundreds of thousands of Tags).

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j uses Lucene indices internally for fulltext search.

Based on [this page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html) from the user guide, it appears that the default indexing 'type' is `exact` using the Lucene Keyword Analyzer which doesn't tokenize the input.

What that means, is that without changing this indexing setting you can only run queries that match the entire tag name (in the case of your example, you're running a wildcard query `'*.country.*'` which matches the whole tag string).

What I think you *actually* want, based on your stated requirements is tokenization in whitespace (`type=fulltext`) *at the time you insert the graph data*, so that the tag field actually contains one token per word:  1-i 2-love 3-my 4-country, any one of which can match a query term (without needing wildcards:  eg "country" or "I love my chocolate")

Comment: but the issue is that I want whole sentence  in one TAG because I also have to show to the user these tags.

Comment: The indexing setting should only apply to the way the "indexed data" (the variants used for matching) is tokenized. This shouldn't prevent Neo4j from storing/returning the original tag string for display.